# Text in \dictum in justification

Tags: koma-script, epigraphs

I use a scrreprt, and place an epigraph like this before the chapter beginning:

```
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\setchapterpreamble{%
\dictum[Lewis Carroll]{
Begin at the beginning, and go on till you come to the end: then stop.}}
```

The text then appears in flushleft "typography" (= raggedright). With

```
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\centering}
```

I can change the typography to centered (or similar to flushrigt). Is there any way to have the dictum text in justification (like the normal text)? I consulted the KOMA guide (Section 3.17), but did not find an answer there

Comment: Could you provide a short, but complete, compileable example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand*\raggeddictumtext{}
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\renewcommand*\raggeddictumtext{}
\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble{%
\dictum[Lewis Carroll]{%
  Begin at the beginning, and go on till you come to the end: then stop.}}
\chapter{Chapter}
\end{document}
```